# VS Code Workspace launch configuration section does not work

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My VS Code Workspace file includes a launch configuration and tasks section, so a developer can run the Azure Functions local.

But it seams that the launch configuration from workspace file will be ignored.

If i add `launch.json` and `tasks.json` with the same content, it works without any problems.

`.code-workspace`:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach",
                "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "clean",
                "command": "dotnet",
                "args": [
                    "clean",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ],
                "type": "process",
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            },
            {
                "label": "build",
                "command": "dotnet",
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ],
                "type": "process",
                "dependsOn": "clean",
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            },
            {
                "label": "clean release",
                "command": "dotnet",
                "args": [
                    "clean",
                    "--configuration",
                    "Release",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ],
                "type": "process",
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            },
            {
                "label": "publish",
                "command": "dotnet",
                "args": [
                    "publish",
                    "--configuration",
                    "Release",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ],
                "type": "process",
                "dependsOn": "clean release",
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            },
            {
                "type": "func",
                "dependsOn": "build",
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ProjectAbc/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2"
                },
                "command": "host start",
                "isBackground": true,
                "problemMatcher": "$func-watch"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
If i press `F5` the lauch configuration from workspace settings should be used to build and run the Azure functions.

**Actual Behavior:**
If i press `F5` VS Code want to create a `launch.json` file based on an environment.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduce your error,

**This is the solution:**

Please notice that Global launch configuration need you to add `launch` in user settings.

[Have a look of this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration).

Your settings.json file should be like this:

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "JavaScript",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "npm prune",

    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9229,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/TimerTrigger/index.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js"
        }
    ]
    }
        //---------------------------
"tasks":{
    "version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clean",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "clean release",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean release",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "type": "func",
            "dependsOn": "build",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ProjectAbc/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2"
            },
            "command": "host start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch"
        }
    ]
    }
}
    }
```

Then you will never face that error. The VS Code will never try to create the launch.json file again.

Then It should work, please notice that your tasks configure is not correct! Your current problem comes from the tasks config not read by VSCode. Modify it and it should work fine.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an error : "Could not find func host start"

Comment: @DerDani81  Can not find func host start? Have you install the function core tools, and where you install that, on local or on global?

Comment: Yes, installed global

Comment: Output: 
"Error: The func task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:
{
    "type": "func",
    "dependsOn": "build",
    "command": "host start",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$func-watch"
}
The task will be ignored."

The task is configured within the .code-workspace file

Comment: @DerDani81 Strange... It can works fine on my side. OK. I will research and if work out I will update the answer.

Comment: @DerDani81 Hi, I have update my answer. Please notice that your tasks will not been read by VS Code because the code of your tasks need a parent named 'tasks'. Try to modify and it should work. I don't know what those yellow horizontal lines represent, but it can works well. The name of the json file I used before was settings.json. There were not even these yellow horizontal lines at that time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still not works for me. Please note, that i use c# and coreclr and not node.
btw. Your.code-workspace is missing a "folder" tag. That is  the reason for the lining

Comment: Why not put the `launch data` in the `.confg-workspace`?